# Cycle through jQuery lightbox photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm having trouble knowing how to build the functionality to be able to click to scroll through my photos in the lightbox. I'm thinking a solution could be to iterate through each one and go to the next index with each click, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm new to programming and am trying to build from scratch without a plugin. My code is below, and I've included a link so you can see the project so far.

https://abharms.github.io/Interactive_Photo_Gallery/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="form-container">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="search" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="photos-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 images">
                <a href="photos/01.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields."></a>
                <a href="photos/02.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here."></a>
                <a href="photos/03.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below."></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 images">
                <a href="photos/04.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="It was amazing to see an iceberg up close, it was so cold but didn’t snow today."></a>
                <a href="photos/05.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="The red cliffs were beautiful. It was really hot in the desert but we did a lot of walking through the canyons."></a>
                <a href="photos/06.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Fall is coming, I love when the leaves on the trees start to change color."></a>
            </div>


            <div class="col-3 images">
                <a href="photos/07.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="I drove past this plantation yesterday, everything is so green!"></a>
                <a href="photos/08.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="My summer vacation to the Oregon Coast. I love the sandy dunes!"></a>
                <a href="photos/09.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="We enjoyed a quiet stroll down this countryside lane. "></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 images">
                <a href="photos/10.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Sunset at the coast! The sky turned a lovely shade of orange."></a>
                <a href="photos/11.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="I did a tour of a cave today and the view of the landscape below was breathtaking."></a>
                <a href="photos/12.jpg"><img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="I walked through this meadow of bluebells and got a good view of the snow on the mountain before the fog came in."></a>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gallery.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
form {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

input[type=text] {
    height: 32px;
    width: 58%;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.col-3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-3:first-child {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#overlay img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.imageContainer {
    max-height: 100%
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#caption {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 600px;

}

a.leftArrow,
a.rightArrow {
    padding: 15px;
}

.leftArrow,
.rightArrow {
    color: white;
    font-size: 56px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22%;
}

.leftArrow {
    left: 12%;
}

.rightArrow {
    right: 12%;
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 820px ) {

.row {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.photos-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
 .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.col-3:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 460px;
}

.leftArrow,
.rightArrow {
    top: 35%;
}

.leftArrow {
    left: 18%;
}

.rightArrow {
    right: 18%;
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .photos-container {
        width: 980px;
    }

    .leftArrow,
    .rightArrow {
        top: 40%;
    }

    .leftArrow {
        left: 20%;
    }

    .rightArrow {
        right: 20%;
    }

}
```

jQuery

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $imageContainer = $('<div class="imageContainer"></div>')
var $caption = $('<p id="caption"></p>');
var $image = $("<img>");
var $leftArrow = $('<a href="#" class="leftArrow" onclick="prev(); return false;"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
var $rightArrow = $('<a href="#" class="rightArrow" onclick="next(); return false;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

//Add image container to overlay
$overlay.append($imageContainer);

//Add image to overlay
$imageContainer.append($image);

//Add navigation arrows to overlay
$imageContainer.append($leftArrow);
$imageContainer.append($rightArrow);

//Add caption to image
$overlay.append($caption);
//add overlay
$("body").append($overlay);


//capture click event on a link to an image
$(".images a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");

    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
    $overlay.show();

    //get child's alt attribute and set caption
    var $captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    $caption.text($captionText);
});


$overlay.click(function(){
    $overlay.hide();
})

$(".leftArrow").bind("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".rightArrow").bind("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}); 

function next() {
    $($image).each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $($caption).hide();
        $($image).next();
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your script with a working version. Let me know if it does what you want.

I refactored your code a bit by removing `next()` and `prev()` onclick handlers. I also move all the code to render image with alt text in a helper function. The cycling logic is exactly like what you expected.

Cheers

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $imageContainer = $('<div class="imageContainer"></div>')
var $caption = $('<p id="caption"></p>');
var $image = $("<img>");
var $leftArrow = $('<a href="#" class="leftArrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
var $rightArrow = $('<a href="#" class="rightArrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
var $links = $(".images a");
var current_index;
//Add image container to overlay
$overlay.append($imageContainer);

//Add image to overlay
$imageContainer.append($image);

//Add navigation arrows to overlay
$imageContainer.append($leftArrow);
$imageContainer.append($rightArrow);

//Add caption to image
$overlay.append($caption);
//add overlay
$("body").append($overlay);


//capture click event on a link to an image
$(".images a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    current_index = $links.index($(this));
    renderImage($(this));
    $overlay.show();    
});


$overlay.click(function(){
    $overlay.hide();
})

$(".leftArrow").bind("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var image = $(".images a").eq(--current_index);
    renderImage(image);
});

$(".rightArrow").bind("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var image = $(".images a").eq(++current_index);
    renderImage(image);
});

function renderImage($link) {
  var imageLocation = $link.attr("href");
  var $captionText = $link.children("img").attr("alt");
  $caption.text($captionText);
  $image.attr("src", imageLocation);

  // Hide next arrow if end of images array
  if (current_index >= $links.length - 1) {
    $rightArrow.hide();
  } else {
    $rightArrow.show();
  }
  // Hide prev arrow if beginning of images array    
  if (current_index <= 0) {
    $leftArrow.hide();
  } else {
    $leftArrow.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly! I very much appreciate your response, this helps tremendously with my learning.